# PHP Array from mysql assoc

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Confusing my values so messy

**Home Code**

```
$user = getventList();
    $response = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($user) > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user)){
         $response[] = $row;
         echo json_encode($response);
    }
    } else {
         return false;
    }


enter code here
```

**Function event**
this one is function to generate result from mysql

> $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from event where status = '2'");
>         return $result;

**Bad Result**

```
[  {"cPID":"123","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"} 
]

[  {"cPID":"123","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"}
]

[  {"cPID":"123","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"12345","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"}
]

[  {"cPID":"123","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"12345","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"123456","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"}
]

[  {"cPID":"123","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"12345","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"123456","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234567","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"}
]
```

**i wanna get only like the last array**

```
[  {"cPID":"123","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"12345","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"123456","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234567","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"}
]
```

Comment: *This extension MySQL was deprecated in PHP 5.5.0, and it was removed in PHP 7.0.0. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.* And if you start to use MySQLi,  you will be able to simplify your code  to `json_encode(mysqli_fetch_all($user, MYSQLI_ASSOC));`

Comment: Thank you sir, i didn't know it was removed on PHP 7.0.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move `json_encode` out of the while loop. Additionally quit using `mysql` and start using `mysqli` or `PDO` functions.

```
$user = getventList();
    $response = array();
    if(mysql_num_rows($user) > 0){
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($user)){
         $response[] = $row;          
    }
    } else {
         return false;
    }
    echo json_encode($response);
```

Now your output will be the expected one

```
[  {"cPID":"123","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"12345","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"123456","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"},
   {"cPID":"1234567","image_event":"enjoy.jpg"}
]
```